# Sharepoint workflow designer call web service

Tags: web-services

```
https://[siteurl]/sites/dev/_api/web/siteusers(@v)?@v=%27i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7C[username]%40mydomain.onmicrosoft.com%27
```

I  called this web serive to get the user id, but the workflow stopped.

**Error :**

> Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute.
>   Details of last request: HTTP InternalServerError to
>   https://[sitesurl]/sites/dev/_api/web/lists(guid'68a69104-957e-4de3-ad44-878e55253f8e')/Items
>   Correlation Id: d96d0819-7175-0401-8825-894ffceb9552 Instance Id:
>   45b15e4a-616f-41c2-871b-6d0cae099206
>
> Invalid text value.

But I can enter it by my browser.

Comment: The error seems not the same as the web service that i called, what happen?

Comment: which user ID do you want to get? From the current logged in user? Or a specific one?

Comment: I want to get the specific one

Answer (score 0):

If it was working fine and now is not - Check to see if the user profile service has stopped working within your environment